# I want to store the detail's in custom variable any one know how to done this?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-variable

I want to store the detail in custom variable any one know how to done this?

```
like {{order_number}},{{order_price}}
```

[image]

i want set variable at backend.

Comment: are you working with custom email?

Comment: nop. need sms template. please check updated question.

Comment: you want to replace with actual value when you send the sms?

Comment: yes when order is place replace with the actual order_number, tracking_number as so on.

Comment: any solution for this?? @QaisarSatti

Comment: i put the solution just that as your requirement. the email templates.

Answer (score 3):

```
$searchReplaceArray = array(
  '{{order_number}}' => $order->getIncrementId(), 
  '{{order_price}}' => $order->getGrandTotal()
);
$result = str_replace(
  array_keys($searchReplaceArray), 
  array_values($searchReplaceArray), 
  $string
);
```

Comment: yes logic is correct but not for me. i am using SMS country module and in this all file encrypt.  $this->getHelper()->sendSms($messageType); except this module only. ant other ways to add variable and assign value.

Comment: did you check the output of this `$messageType`?

Comment: its just status which type of msg. its set static value. $messageType = 'order'; $messageType = 'invoice';  $title = 'Shipment SMS'; like this.

Comment: the solution for you at run time update the database value before sending the message after sending  change to previous. this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I am not sure it's will work or not but just putting my idea here.
Creating a custom variable for the email can be too much time consuming, so the easiest way to get this result would be using a .phtml file on your transactional email.

Add this to your email HTML:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/custom/mynote.phtml' order=$order}}
```

Create a file **path/to/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/custom/mynote.phtml**

Now in this file you could do something like this:

```
$order = $this->getOrder();

$note = $order->getNote(); // (or whatever is the code for getting the note message)

echo $note;
```

Done :)